# Package external jars in mdb jar

Tags: java, jboss7.x

I developed MDB (say mymdb.jar) using Maven/Eclipse and I am deploying it in JBOSS 7.2. It works.

But, when I add have external jars such as http client 4.3.4, maven compiles it but these external jars are not packaged with the existing mymdb.jar

mdb.jar contains
com/test/MyMDB
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
META-INF/ejb-jar.xml
META-INF/jboss-ejb3.xml
META-INF/maven

How do I have maven package external jars such as http-client-4.3.4.jar and reference it from my application.

Note: This is not a .war or .ear file. It is a .jar with a MDB that implements onMessage method

Comment: Typically, you want dependent libraries to go into WEB-INF/lib in your .war.  If so, you'd include them in your war's pom.xml.

Comment: Try maven-assembly-plugin. See here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven